# Symfony 3.4: How to mock app.request inside twig template

Tags: request, mocking, twig, phpunit, symfony-3.4

Let's say I have the following method

```
  public function prepareEmail($dataModel)
    {
        return $this->container->get('templating')->render(
            'MyBundle:Emails:email-document.html.twig',
             [
                 'data' => $dataModel,
             ]
        )
    }
```

I want to test a very complicated logic that I have in my twig template.

In my phpunit test kit I'm not mocking `TwigEngine` service so I'm working with a fully rendered templates.

In my test I doing something like this

```
public function testPrepareEmail()
{
    $template = $this->manager->prepareEmail($testData);

    static::assertContains('some part of template', $template);
}
```

Everything looks good, but I'm added the following string to one of my templates

`{{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost() }}`

And now I'm getting error

`Twig_Error_Runtime : Impossible to invoke a method ("getSchemeAndHttpHost") on a null variable.`

which is very reasonable, the question is how to mock Symfony `Request` object in my case?

Comment: is there an option for not trying to access request from inside of the template?

Comment: Create a (mocking) class `Request` and add that one as a global `$this->container->get('templating')->addGlobal('app', [ 'request' => new Request(), ]);`